# Looking for a good way to split a string on all-capital words

Tags: python, regex, string

For example I have an arbitrary string:

`var = 'I have a string I want GE and APPLES but nothing else'`

What's the best way to split the string in python so that I can obtain just `'GE'` and `'APPLES'`. In Java I'd split on spaces and then check each array element for two or more consecutive letters and grab the ones that do.

Is there a better way to do it in Python, I'm not particularly well versed in Python's regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.isupper`, `str.split` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> var = 'I have a string I want GE and APPLES but nothing else'
>>> [x for x in var.split() if x.isupper() and len(x) > 1 ]
['GE', 'APPLES']
```

Using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b', var)
['GE', 'APPLES']
```

**Timing comparison:**

```
>>> var = 'I have a string I want GE and APPLES but nothing else'*10**5
>>> %timeit [x for x in var.split() if x.isupper() and len(x) > 1 ]
1 loops, best of 3: 773 ms per loop
>>> %timeit re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b', var)
1 loops, best of 3: 491 ms per loop
```

#Input with huge words:

```
>>> var = ' '.join(['FOO'*1000, 'bar'*1000, 'SPAM'*1000]*1000)
>>> %timeit [x for x in var.split() if x.isupper() and len(x) > 1 ]
1 loops, best of 3: 224 ms per loop
>>> %timeit re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b', var)
1 loops, best of 3: 483 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome, would you mind a quick explanation of `\b` or where a good link to learn `re` I tried looking up the `re` package before but it was a tad overwhelming

Comment: @sreya Docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, `\b` is used for word-boundaries.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Which of these would be more efficient in a large text file?

Comment: @Matt Regex version is fast.

Comment: @Matt That depends on the word size I guess, tested both solutions with huge words and this time regex solution came out to be slower. See my updated answer for results.

Comment: Interesting results. Thanks for the test output!

Comment: Last question, if I were to modify it to include strings such as `'GE'` *or* strings that are capital and may include numbers `'G4'` how would you modify it?

Comment: @sreya I think the list comprehension version will work as is, and you need to change the regex to `r'\b[A-Z4]{2,}\b'`. Include any character that you want to match inside the character class.